# Android and exception on introducing own custom key store

Tags: android, exception, ssl, keystore

I'm generating a keystore from a certificate as follows:

```
export CLASSPATH=/Developer/BouncyCastle/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar
CERTSTORE=~/bitbucket/Android/CoooriJED/res/raw/mykeystore.bks
if [ -a $CERTSTORE ]; then
        rm $CERTSTORE || exit 1
fi
keytool \
        -importcert \
        -v \
        -trustcacerts \
        -alias 0 \
        -file <(openssl x509 -in mycert.pem) \
        -keystore $CERTSTORE \
        -storetype BKS \
        -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
        -providerpath /Developer/BouncyCastle/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar \
        -storepass password
```

This generates a key store without apparent problem. In Eclipse I clean my Android project and see "mykeystore.bks" in the raw folder. I load the key store as follows:

```
private KeyStore keyStore()
{
    try {
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mykeystore);
        try {
            trusted.load(in, "password".toCharArray()); // *Throws an exception*
        } finally {
        in.close();
        }
        return trusted;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

I call this method as follows (I've removed the exception handling to make it easier to read here):

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
kmf.init(keyStore(), "password".toCharArray());
```

However, the line `trusted.load(in, "password".toCharArray())` is causing a "Wrong version of key store" IOException to be thrown. Why is that?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Can you list the contents of the contents of the file with keytool? Is the password correct? What version of Android are you testing this on? BTW, if it only contains certificates, you don't need the KeyManagerFactory, etc. calls. Those are for private keys.

Comment: Android 2.1, 2.3 and 4.0. Password is correct.

Comment: So is the file readable on your development machine?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are using wrong version of `bcprov jar`? There are different versions of it and you need to choose the one that corresponds to your java sdk:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html